How to invoke click on Parent with ripple when child is clicked?


@Composable
fun Test() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
            // parent Click
        }
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                // child Click
            }
        ) {
            Column {
                Text("Hi")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp))
                Text("Test")
            }
            Text("Test2")
        }
    }
}



Is it possible to trigger the parent component's clickEvent of a Column when the child component's clickEvent of a Row is executed in the same code? If possible, I also need a ripple effect where clicking on the child component applies to the entire parent

By writing a custom gesture that does not consume down, unlike clickable, you can propagate click from child to parent.
And by adding a parent MutableInteractionSource to this gesture you can invoke parents indication when child is clicked.
Result

Gesture
fun Modifier.clickableCustom(
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource,
    parenInteractionSource: MutableInteractionSource? = null,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) = this.then(
    Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
        coroutineScope {
            awaitEachGesture {
                val down = awaitFirstDown()

                val pressInteraction = PressInteraction.Press(down.position)
                launch {
                    interactionSource.emit(pressInteraction)
                    parenInteractionSource?.emit(pressInteraction)
                }

                val up = waitForUpOrCancellation()

                if (up != null) {
                    launch {
                        interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Release(pressInteraction))
                        parenInteractionSource?.emit(PressInteraction.Release(pressInteraction))
                    }
                    onClick()
                } else {
                    launch {
                        interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Cancel(pressInteraction))
                        parenInteractionSource?.emit(PressInteraction.Cancel(pressInteraction))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
)

Demo
@Preview
@Composable
fun ClickParentTest() {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val interactionSourceChild = remember {
        MutableInteractionSource()
    }

    val interactionSourceParent = remember {
        MutableInteractionSource()
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .indication(interactionSourceParent, rememberRipple())
            .clickableCustom(
                interactionSourceParent
            ) {
                // parent Click
                Toast.makeText(context, "Parent click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            .border(2.dp, Color.Blue)
            .padding(20.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                .size(200.dp)
                .indication(interactionSourceChild, rememberRipple())
                .clickableCustom(
                    interactionSource = interactionSourceChild,
                    parenInteractionSource = interactionSourceParent
                ) {
                    // child Click
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Child click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        ) {
            Column {
                Text("Hi")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp))
                Text("Test")
            }
            Text("Test2")
        }
    }
}

